# Basic socket.io application not working

Tags: python, django, socket.io

I created and ran a `nodejs` file `server.js`:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080); 
io.set('log level', 1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // pass  
});
```

and a client `client.js`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var connected = function(){
    console.log("connect")
    }

    var start = function() {
        socket = new io.Socket();
        socket.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('connect', connected);
    };
    start();
}
```

I included `socket.io`:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but in the debugger I look:
Request URL:http: //undefined/socket.io/1/?t=1359905123022

I'm using django, and I ran django server in 8000 port...

WTF?

Answer (score 1):

try to replace this lines in client.js:

```
socket = new io.Socket();
socket.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

to:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

Comment: since the official django-socketio is telling you wrong, this is a lifesaver :)